# Is there some kind of tear image animation effect for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, tearing

I wonder if there exists some kind of tear apart image animation effect with jQuery today?
Not like into one millions pieces, but instead like tearing a picture apart effect at the middle? Moving towards the sides. Or is this something which requires the use of Flash animations??
Thanks!

Comment: I think is a HTML5 Canvas question. Using drawImage, then moving the pixels about.

Comment: Please explain a little more. I checked it up but there doesnt seem to be any specific difference whatsoever.

Comment: You could use Flash if you want. Some people don't like it and prefer Canvas. If you don't have Flash then you can get a 1 month free trial but then you have to buy it.

Comment: Based on what I`ve seen so far, I feel like Flash is the best way to go on forth with this? What do you PERSONALLY think?

Comment: I prefer canvas but you've got to be aware that it is quite new and lots of people won't have a modern browser so if you want a wider audience you'll need Flash or something simpler such as an image you split into 2 half images that move apart by animation eg by jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with javascript and css3.

Simply have javascript duplicate an image (probably a div with the background as an image) and paste it over itself. Then have the left image show the first pixels 0 to 50% and the right image should show pixels 50% to 100% with the background aligned right. You can then have css or jquery move each side apart. You would need to add some extra styles to create that rip look but it is completely doable.

Comment: Oh Ok, thanks I`ll take a look at this as soon as I decide what image to use. ;)

Comment: If you can consider this your answer, please mark it as so :)

Comment: I`ll have to see if I`m able to accomplish something, expect some points most likely today or tomorrow ;)